# Lua wait for log file to be closed

Tags: lua, wait

I have a script that is executed via a function `LuaExportStop()` that is called when a program is stopped.

The same function is used by other scripts. One of those other scripts writes and closes a log file when that function is called. I want to import that log file, parse the contents and write the results to another file or possibly to a MySql DB down the road. I have accomplished the code to do this with a static copy of the file in question.

I believe the problem I am having is that both scripts execute with the same function at the same time so an error is thrown when my script tries to access a file that is open and/or being written.

My question is can I have my script "wait" until the file has been closed to execute? How would this be implemented around this code?

```
luaExportStop()

        local filePath = "h:\\somepath\\stats.log"
        newFile = io.open(filePath, "w")
        dofile("this is the log file")
        newFile:write(pp(stats))
        newFile:close()

end
```

Comment: To summarize the problem, you have two different programs running at the same time that are trying to append to the same file. Is that correct?

Comment: What means `dofile("this is the log file")`?  You can't run a log file.  You can only run a Lua script.

Comment: Try wrapping the function in pcall(...) then retry if it fails

Comment: @luther I am trying to read the log...which is actually a lua table with my script and then converting the lua table into a json object and writing that object to another file.

Comment: @egor the dofile is loading the lua table which is what the "log file" consists of. That part of the code works as expected when a static copy of the file is used, the problem only seems to happen when the other script is accessing the file which makes sense. I just want to wait until the file is closed by the other script.

Comment: @mike67 I will give that a try. I haven't used pcall before so I will look into that. Went away for the weekend so I will have to try when I get back.